# find the two longest word made of other words

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I want to find two longest words from array ,made from smaller words. my code are given below.

**current out put is:**

> catxdogcatsrat, ratcatdogcat, catsdogcats, dogcatsdog

**required output is:**

> ratcatdogcat, catsdogcats

```
class program 
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        string[] stringrray =   { "cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "catxdogcatsrat", "dog", "dogcatsdog",
                                 "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat" };

        list2.Add(stringrray[0]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[1]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[2]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[3]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[4]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[5]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[6]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[7]);
        list2.Add(stringrray[8]);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        var mod = list2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();
        int j = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < mod.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mod.Count-j; i++)
            {
                if (mod[i].Contains(mod[mod.Count - j]))
                {
                    j++;
                    list.Add(mod[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        var mod1 = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length);
        foreach (var i in mod1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't ```ratcatdogcat``` a valid word, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
string[] stringrray = { "cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "catxdogcatsrat", "dog", "dogcatsdog", "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(stringrray);
List<string> Finallist = new List<string>();
char[] smallstrchar = String.Join("", list2.Where(x => x.Length <= 4)).ToCharArray();
char[] bigstrchar = String.Join("", list2.Where(x => x.Length > 4)).ToCharArray();
char[] modchar = bigstrchar.Except(smallstrchar).ToArray();

foreach(string bigstr in list2)
{
    if(!(bigstr.IndexOfAny(modchar) != -1))
    {
        Finallist.Add(bigstr);
    }
}
Finallist = Finallist.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Take(2).ToList();
foreach(string finalstr in Finallist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(finalstr);
}
```

So first is the `stringrray` which contains all the strings which are supposed to be taken care and find the longest one out of it. With your code it also takes the string which contains `x` in them but all other chars are matched. So I have made a list of strings in `list2` which contains all the values. Then splitted the list2 in 2 parts that is `smallstrchar` array contains all the chars of the smaller strings less than length of 4 and `Bigstrchar` contains all chars of strings which are bigger than length of 5. Now `Except` takes out all the chars which does not exsist in the smallstrchar and present in Bigstrchar. Now we have the list of chars which need to be excluded from the sort.

Finally `IndexOfAny` to find in that string contains that char or not. If not then add to Finallist. Later we can take 2 from the list.

Hope this helps

Comment: actually catxdogcatsrat is  not the word that is made of other smaller word. because it contains x which is not a word so i want to remove  catxdogcatsrat from out put

Comment: That means your first loop is not finding the right values

Comment: I have another program but it finds only one value .

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33266/write-a-program-to-find-the-longest-word-made-of-other-words . kindly refer this link it find only one longest value i need two longest value

Comment: Can we remove dependance of min. and max length.

Comment: Sure can. Than lemme what would be the logic? How are we going to distinguish the chars which we wanted to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify adding the array to list2 with

```
list2.AddRange(stringrray)
```

Comment: yes this  is  right way for assigning array in list but there is  no changes in output.

Answer (score 0):

### You may use this code...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>() { "cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "catxdogcatsrat", "dog", "dogcatsdog", "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat" };
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    // solution 1
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (IsCombinationOf(word, words))
        {
            result.Add(word);
        }
    }

    // solution 2
    result = words.Where(x => IsCombinationOf(x, words)).ToList();
}

public static bool IsCombinationOf(string word, List<string> parts)
{
    // removing the actual word just to be secure.
    parts = parts.Where(x => x != word).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();

    // erase each part in word. Only those which are not in the list will remain.
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        word = Regex.Replace(word, part, "");
    }

    // if there are any caracters left, it hasn't been a combination
    return word.Length == 0;
}
```

### but...

This code has a little bug. The `OrderbyDescending` clause ensures that `cats` will be removed before `cat`. Otherwise the `s` would remain and the code wouldn't work as expected. But if we use some fictional values this code will not work properly. For example:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "abz", "e", "zefg", "f", "g", "abzefg" };
```

Let's have a look at `abzef`. The algorithm will remove `zefg` first, but then it's not possible to go any futher. Indeed, the word is a combination of `abz`, `e`, `f` and `g` .